# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p} + \zeta_{p}^{-1}]$ is the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p} + \zeta_{p}^{-1})$

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm a bit at a loss about what I can say in this situation. Do I have to show that $\zeta_{p} + \zeta_{p}^{-1}$ form an integral basis ? If I do, I have no idea how to do it.

If not, can I use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p} + \zeta_{p}^{-1}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ at my advantage ?

Thanks in advance for any hint or answer,

Jérôme

Comment: Let $\tau_p=\zeta_p+\zeta_p^{-1}$, then you have to prove that $\tau_p$ forms a power basis, this means that the $1,\tau,\tau^2,\ldots$ form an integral basis.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it seems I lack some results which could help me proving that $\tau_{p}$ is an algebraic integer.

Comment: It is not an easy problem. Some things that could be useful are lacking like a nice form of the minimal polynomial of $\tau_p$ and the lack of knowledge of the discriminant of the ring of algebraics. Where does this question come from?

Comment: I don't have a book reference. It comes from my teacher as a homework. Could it help to know that $p$ is an odd prime ? I just noticed I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Have you seen cyclotomic extensions?

Comment: Yes, even if I'm still not an expert in manipulating them.

Comment: Have you seen that the $\zeta^n$ form a power basis?

Comment: Got a warning to avoid discussions in comments :'( . I know what it is but I didn't see any result about it (or I forgot them because it has been a long time).

Comment: I got a message that you don't have enough reputation to chat:(

Comment: I was perhaps rude with my previous comment, sorry. It's just that I'm trying to understand something and nowhere can I find an example which could show me a way to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\tau_p=\zeta_{p} + \zeta_{p}^{-1}$ then since  $\bar{\zeta_p}=\zeta_{p}^{-1}$ we have that $\tau_p \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $\mathbb{Q}(\tau_p) \subset \mathbb{R}$. We know that $\{\zeta,\zeta^2,\ldots,\zeta^{p-1}\}$ form an integral basis for the cyclotomic integers. Let $a=\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}b_i\zeta_p^i$ be a real cyclotomic integer, then $a=\bar{a}$. Since  $\bar{\zeta_p^i}=\zeta_p^{p-i}$ we must have $b_i=b_{p-1}$ but then $a=\sum_{i=1}^{(p-1)/2}\tau_p^i$ which shows that the $\{\tau,\tau^2,\ldots,\tau^{(p-1)/2}\}$ form an integer basis of the real quaternion integers.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of writing the general form of a real cyclotomic integer.
Thank you very much. I read it carefully. I still have some questions, unfortunately.
The deduction that $a = \overline{a}$, do we use it here ? Is it that evident ?

Comment: If you think this is the answer to this question then please check my answer as "accepted".

Comment: Note: this proof also works for n non prime replacing p in the question. Of course, for such n, p-1 in the power should be replaced by $\varphi(n) - 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You show that every element of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p} + \zeta_{p}^{-1})$ which is a root of a monic integer polynomial is actually in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p} + \zeta_{p}^{-1}]$.

Comment: Thanks for answering this quickly. Do I use the contradiction : Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p} + \zeta_{p}^{-1}) $ a root of a monic integer polynomial. We suppose that $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p} + \zeta_{p}^{-1}]$. And we get a contradiction ? Or is there something more direct ?